# Aviary crop presets not working on iOS

Tags: ios, aviary

I'm trying to force users to crop their photo to a square with Aviary. As described in the [Aviary documentation here](https://developers.aviary.com/staticdocs/ios/Classes/AFPhotoEditorCustomization.html#//api/name/setCropToolOriginalEnabled:), it is possible to disable custom crops and specify the presets manually. I am attempting the following:

```
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolOriginalEnabled:NO];
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolCustomEnabled:NO];
NSDictionary *SIZE = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"kAFCropPresetName",@"square",
                      @"kAFCropPresetWidth",@"1.0f",
                      @"kAFCropPresetHeight",@"1.0f",
                      nil];
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolPresets:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:SIZE, nil]];
```

But this does not work. This results is 0 cropping options:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the below code:

`[AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolOriginalEnabled:NO];
    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolCustomEnabled:NO];
    NSDictionary * square = @{kAFCropPresetName: @"Square", kAFCropPresetHeight : @(1.0f), kAFCropPresetWidth : @(1.0f)};
    [AFPhotoEditorCustomization setCropToolPresets:@[square]];`

Comment: Not working in my case.. As library is changed with Adobe, Even used AdobeImageEditorCustomization instead of AFPhotoEditorCustomization.